# Job spark blocked and runs indefinitely

Tags: apache-spark

We encounter a problem on a Spark job 1.6(on yarn) that never ends, whene several jobs launched simultaneously.
We found that by launching the job spark in yarn-client mode we do not have this problem, unlike launching it in yarn-cluster mode.
it could be a trail to find the cause.

we changed the code to add a sparkContext.stop ()
Indeed, the SparkContext was created (val sparkContext = createSparkContext) but not stopped. this solution has allowed us to decrease the number of jobs that remains blocked but nevertheless we still have some jobs blocked.

by analyzing the logs we have found this log that repeats without stopping:

```
17/09/29 11:04:37 DEBUG SparkEventPublisher: Enqueue SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate(1,WrappedArray())
17/09/29 11:04:41 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: Sending progress
17/09/29 11:04:41 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: Number of pending allocations is 0. Sleeping for 5000.
```

it seems that the job block whene we call newAPIHadoopRDD to get data from Hbase. it may be the issue !! 
Does someone have any idea about this issue ? 
Thank you in advance